# Authentication in MEANJS for new module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meanjs

I have a problem in the MEAN stack to deal with the authentication.

Indeed I have created a new module called "Wallet" and here is its model:

```
var WalletSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  bitcoinAddresses: {
    type: Object,
    default: []
  },
  fringe: {
    type: Array
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: 'User id cannot be blank'
  }
});
```

So it is referencing to the user Id and I'd like to load the wallet automatically with the user when my pages are loaded.

I mean everything is working correctly except that when I am refreshing my pages the User is loaded correctly but not the wallet that is causing errors then.

Is there a way to load my wallet at the same time I load my user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set the reference in Wallet you should start by getting the Wallet first. This examples assumes u use mongoose.

```
Wallet.findOne({'_id': id}).
 populate({
       path: 'user',
       model: 'User'
}).exec().
then(function (wallet) {//Here is a wallet object with user filled.}).
catch(function(err){//Handle the error});
```

As a side note: it might be better to reference the Wallet in the User schema.

Comment: Yes that was I was thinking to load the wallet at the beginning of the page.

But the wallet is also referenced in the User model. Could I load it directly from the User model ?

Comment: So you have set a link from User to Wallet and from Wallet to User?

You could do the exact same with the User Schema just change the populate path and model.

Comment: Yes there is a link but I don't really understand how populate works. It is gonna initialise my wallet when loading the user ??

Comment: When you normally query User without the populate, the reference to Wallet will just contain it's ObjectId. Populate replaces this field with the referenced Wallet Document. You can add a select inside the populate query to select the fields you want.

I suggest looking at this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html